# Factorization Machine Algorithms And Implementations For Implicit Feedback?

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system

Spark ASL supports only (user, item, measure) implicit pairs, libfm supports any number of features but no implicit feedback ranking (only classification/regression).

Is there good articles/implementations about algorithms that allow any number of features and support implicit feedback?